# To get text box value from another form in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to get textbox value from a form to another form. I used,

```
Private Sub lblok_Click()
Status=[Forms]![frmNew]![txtstatus]
.....
End Sub
```

Once I click, I get the following error

```
Run-time error '2450':
Microsfor Access cannot find the referenced form 'frmNew'.
```

How do I get the textbox value from the other form to this form. Please suggest. Thank you

Comment: It's either misspelled or not open or a subform.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by form is not open, because its spelled correctly and not a sub form.

Comment: Well, `frmNew` must be open in form view for this to work.

Comment: Is there any other way we can make this work without having the form open?

Comment: Assuming frmNew is opened at some point in process, set a global variable or TempVars variable which can then still be referenced when frmNew is closed. Or use OpenArgs to pass value to a form when it is opened.

Comment: If the form isn't open, the textbox *doesn't exist* and has no value. If it is bound to a table, read the value from there. If unbound, do as June7 wrote.